# Is there any way to get content type's data (dropdown data)?

Tags: contentful, contentful-api

I'm working on contentful to create blog posts.
I have created a field named with category with dropdown data, like the below image.
I have created more blogs for each categories (Ex: game has 5 blogs, Tour has 10 blogs and etc).
I want to show the list of all categories with content counts,
Is there any possible to get all of the categories with content count? ( I can get it by getting all blogs using this query
`const res = ContentfulService.getEntries({ content_type: 'blog'})`
then I grouped with category, but to get the category only, I don't want to get all of the blogs.)

[image]

Please let me know if there is a solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved that using graphQL,

const query =
{
categoryCollection
{
items{
linkedFrom {
blogCollection {
total
}
}
name:category
sys {
id
}
}
}
}

let categories = await fetch(`https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/${spaceId}`, {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
// Authenticate the request
Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
},
// send the GraphQL query
body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
})

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this through the API would be to make a request for each category and look at the `total` property of the response and that would be less efficient than what you're already suggesting.

[https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/{space_id}/environments/{environment_id}/entries?access_token={access_token}&content_type={content_type}&fields.category[in]={categoryValue}](https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/%7Bspace_id%7D/environments/%7Benvironment_id%7D/entries?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D&content_type=%7Bcontent_type%7D&fields.category%5Bin%5D=%7BcategoryValue%7D)